# what is the signification of ** in python (when not a mathematical expression)

Tags: python

here is a small portion of code

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.MultiDiGraph()
...
G.add_edge(white, black, **game)
```

(game is a dictionnary)
what is the role of ** in the last line

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/343834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `add_edge` gets passed in the dictionary `game` as [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments). For example, the following two are equivalent:

```
game = {'weight': 5, 'color': 'blue'}
G.add_edge(white, black, **game)
```

```
G.add_edge(white, black, weight=5, color='blue')
```

Answer (score 4):

`**` is the operator which unpacks mapping types (e.g. a `dict`) into keyword arguments.

Consider:

```
def foo(bar=1):
   print bar

d = {'bar':2}
foo(**d)
```

In this example, `2` will be printed.  On the other side, you can also absorb all unknown keyword arguments in a `**kwargs` type variable:

```
def foo(a=1,b=2,**kwargs):
    print kwargs

foo(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

Of course, you can combine these forms as well:

```
def foo(a=1,b=2,**kwargs):
    print b
    print kwargs

d = {'b':3, 'c':4}
foo(**d)
```

Answer (score 1):

It expands a dictionary so its key-pair values are used as named parameters. Consider, for example, this function:

```
>>> def f(a, b, c):
...     return a+b-c
...
```

I can call it passing its arguments in the original order:

```
>>> f(1,2,3)
0
```

But I can also switch them if I attribute values to the argument names:

```
>>> f(1,c=3,b=2)
0
```

When one calls a function passing a dictionary preceded by `**`, the pairs of this dictionary will be used as parameters. So, I could create the dictionary below

```
>>> params = {'c':3, 'b':2}
```

...and pass it to my function...

```
>>> f(1,**params)
0
```

...and will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the argument is a dictionary, basically.

It's usually used as `**kwargs`, meaning, keyword arguments.

For instance, when you define a method like:

```
def myMethod(first, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

It means that the second argument is expected to be a collection (a "list" of arguments), and `kwargs` is meant to be a `dict`.